# Looking for Regex for testPathIgnorePatterns in jest config in package.json

Tags: jestjs

Below is folder structure I have

dist

- assets
- bin
- e2e

  - sfn

    - *.test.js
- lib
- resources
- types

In my package.json jest testPathIgnorePatterns I want to add everything inside dist except e2e/sfn/*.test.js

I am trying various regex but they do not work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

regex "/dist/(?!e2e/sfn)" works